# Download data from Bloomberg with R

Tags: programming, bloomberg

I was trying to download daily data from a few tickers from Bloomberg with `Rblpapi`. I wanted all calendar data, not just trading days, but, when I put these options, my data return only with `NA`.

Options:

```
options <- c("periodicitySelection" = "DAILY", 
             "nonTradingDayFillOption" = "NON_TRADING_WEEKDAYS", 
             "nonTradingDayFillMethod" = "NIL_VALUE")

data <- bdh("BCSWFPD BGN Curncy", c("PX_LAST"), start.date = ymd("2000-01-01"), options = options)
```

If I remove the options and leave only the `periodicitySelection`, it works fine.

Comment: Best bet may be to [file an issue](https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi/issues).

Comment: I just checked and there is only data from September 2009 to December 2015, so the first 2500 datapoints and last 1200 or so datapoints are all N/As. Are you sure you didn't receive valid data in the middle of the returned list?

Comment: @assylias If I use only ```periodicitySelection```, I receive data until today.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to check is to load on the terminal.

```
BCSWFPD BGN Curncy GP MAX
```

vs

```
BCSWFPD CMPN Curncy GP MAX
```

You are querrying data that does not exist. CMPN has more history.